# Google Page Insights: did anybody ever optimize images with lossless compression by the amount Google suggests?

Tags: image, optimization, wordpress, image-size

I ran my page through Google's Page Insights to receive the suggestion to optimize my page's images. There are many JPEG photos on it. Google's Page Insights suggest that for some of them there could be savings of up to 50% (for some even over 60%) by using lossless compression. I am not sure which technologies Google bases these calculation on. Had anybody luck matching these numbers with real (lossless) compression results?

I already did some research, tried out "WP Smush.it" and "wwww image optimizer" plugins, both with very similar results being nowhere near for Google suggest would be possible. In fact, for jpeg images, where Google Page Insight mentioned some 53% filesize savings being possible with lossless compression, these tools just managed to save about 3%. I tried this with several of the images, so I would be very interested, if somebody else experienced similar problems? How does Google Page Insights do these kind of calculations? Is it just educated guessing or are they using different compression algorithms that us humans are not allowed to know? ;)

Comment: I'm very confused by these results as well. I losslessly optimized my images, JPGs are save progressively at around 50-70 % quality. I'm not getting it. The suggestions vary between 60 and 80 %.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got the same problem. I managed to reduce the difference from what Google gets to 3% with a software named "RIOT" for windows. Still looking for one that would reproduce the same results Google insight gets.
A solution that doesn't involve linux or being a programmer that is.